# NIC models for HVM guests in Xen 4.0

Tags: networking, windows-xp, xen

Is there a list of NIC models that I should use with various HVM guests in Xen 4.0? Is there even a list of possible choices for the model=field? I'm planning on running both Windows and FreeBSD guests on the particular Xen box that I'm configuring now, and ideally I'd like a setting that can work on both of them and get me gigabit speeds without a lot of extra hassle loading special drivers (similar to VMware's e1000 NIC option). Any suggestions?

The vif line I'm currently using in my config is:

```
vif = [ 'type=ioemu,bridge=eth0,model=ne2k_pci,script=vif-ovs' ]
```

This works in my Windows XP SP3 VM, but is only recognized as a 10Mbit interface. Changing to `model=e1000` or `model=i82557b` resulted in Windows not being able to find a driver for the NIC.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the answer for XEN 3.4 from the XEN-WiKi](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenCommonProblems#head-590a79b0e53661f0a8f2521b06fc4a2b4ef8fce8). If you read this you will find that it depends on the capabilities of qemu-dm - I hope this helps for 4.0.

For Windows I would recommend using a [PV driver](http://jolokianetworks.com/70Knowledge/Virtualization/Open_Source_Windows_Paravirtualization_Drivers_for_Xen).

Comment: Thanks Nils. I've tried several of the different options for PV drivers, and have yet to find one that could in any way qualify as stable in Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: [Propably this one?](http://www.meadowcourt.org/downloads/gplpv_XP_0.11.0.308.msi) there was an article a while back in the german c`t magazine describing that driver in a 0.9 version. On Heise I found another link leading to [XEN Cloud PV drivers for Windows](http://www.xen.org/download/xcp/index.html). On [Heise](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Virtualisation-Xen-is-looking-to-catch-up-by-releasing-version-4-974405.html) it seems that you can use that driver with the OpenSource XEN 4, too.

Comment: +1 for GPLPV drivers on meadowcourt.org. Been using them for 3.5 years (really, first bootup was 01/2009) on some Windows XP 32bit HVM systems without a single itch.

Comment: @JedDaniels it seems I am not the only one who used the GPL-PV-drivers in production.